# Visual Studio 2008 find replace regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio

Is there any ways I can do this?

Find:

```
if (value) _select.Add(X); else _select.Remove(X);
```

and replace with:

```
addToSelect(value1, _select1, X);
```

where X is a variable that I don't know and I want to copy it in the replace.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have Resharper 5 available?

Comment: Ummm ... yes a do. I think I do, because I know I disable it at some point. How can I use that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'find and replace' with the option 'use regular expressions' with this regex :

```
if:b@\(:b@value:b@\):b@\n@:b@\{@:b@\n@:b@_select:b@\.:b@Add:b@\({.#}\):b@;:b@\n@:b@\}@:b@\n@:b@else:b@\n@:b@\{@:b@\n@:b@_select:b@\.:b@Remove:b@\(\1\):b@;:b@\n*:b*\}*
```

and replace it with this :

```
addToSelect(value1, _select1, \1);
```

Thanks to the :b@ and the \n@ it will also catch version with spaces :

```
if (  value  ) _select.  Add(  X  );  else   _select.Remove(  X  ) ;
```

or versions on multiple lines :

```
if (value) 
  _select.Add(X); 
else 
  _select.Remove(X);
```

<strike>One warning however, X appears two times in your Find example. The regex will not check if the second X is equal to the first X. The second X is just ignored and the X in</strike>

```
addToSelect(value1, _select1, \1);
```

will always be the first X.

EDIT : updated the regex to check that the two X's are always equal.

EDIT 2 : updated the regex to also catch versions with { and } :

```
if (value) 
{
  _select.Add(X); 
}
else 
{
  _select.Remove(X);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not have VS2008 but in VS2010 I would try this (not sure whether this option is available in 2008):

1) `Ctrl+Shift+H` or `Edit -> Find and replace -> Replace in files`
2) In `Find options` panel select `use regular expressions`

I'm not a master in regular expressions so I'm not sure whether it will replace with regex or only search with regex while replacing with plain text.

Comment: I've tried that and it didn't work. There is something with "Tagged expression" - {} but I just can't figure it out.